# Unable to upload .p12 certificate from local Mac to remote parse server on AWS ec2 - bitnami

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I am well aware of how to upload .p12 cert for iOS push notifications - via Heroku or Back4App.
However my Parse server is hosted on AWS ec2 instance with Bitnami image.
Hence I can only interact with my server via my Terminal.
I tried uploading the PFX (.p12) from my local machine via scp something like this:

`scp -i /Path/To/My/Certificates.p12 ubuntu@server_ip: /home`

but I am receiving the following error in Terminal:

`Load key "/Path/To/My/Certificates.p12": invalid format ubuntu@server_ip: Permission denied (publickey).`

There is unfortunately poor documentation regarding how to upload p12 files without GUI's like Back4App/Heroku.

So I would be very glad if someone could assist me on this matter.

T.I.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCP is over SSH - so if you know how to log into your instance using SSH then that's half the battle

the -i keyword is a path to your private keyfile, not the file you want to upload, which should be in /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa where "myname" is your account.

how do you normally access the VM over SSH? You will use those creds with scp

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

This should work for you:

scp -i myKey.pem.txt /Path/To/My/Certificates.p12 ubuntu@server_ip:/home

Comment: I normally access with ssh like this: `ssh -I myKey.pem.txt ubuntu@server_ip`. To be frank, I did try something like this: `ssh -I myKey.pem.txt /Path/To/My/Certificates.p12 ubuntu@server_ip: /home` but that didn't go well

Comment: I've edited my original answer to conatin something that should work for you